# How do i push all these array values into one single array?

Tags: angular

I need to pass values in the drill down highcharts,My JSON format isn't working right, so kindly help me with this .

```
this.MemberProvider.totalMonthlyRevenueByBranch(getmonthmonthwisr)
.subscribe(data => {

 this.graphdata =data;
 console.log(this.graphdata);

})
```

My JSON format looks like this,

```
[
   {
      "_id":{
         "year":2018
      },
      "data":[
         {
            "year":2018,
            "total":10260,
            "month":"Mar"
         }
      ],
      "overall":10260
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "year":2019
      },
      "data":[
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14160,
            "month":"Dec"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14160,
            "month":"Nov"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14259,
            "month":"Oct"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14160,
            "month":"Sep"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14259,
            "month":"Aug"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14160,
            "month":"July"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":28518,
            "month":"Jun"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14259,
            "month":"May"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":185185,
            "month":"Apr"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":54739,
            "month":"Mar"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":28518,
            "month":"Feb"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":28518,
            "month":"Jan"
         }
      ],
      "overall":424895
   }
]
```

How to get this kind of JSON structure

```
[
      {
       "year": "2018",
       "Mar": 10260,
       "overall": 10260
      },
      {
        "year": "2019",
        "Jan": 28518,
        "Feb": 28518,
        "Mar": 54739,
        "Apr": 185185,
        "May": 14259,
        "Jun": 28518,
        "July": 14160,
        "Aug": 14259,
        "Sep": 14160,
        "Oct": 14259
        "Nov": 14160
        "Dec": 14160
        "overall": 424895
      }
    ];
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please provide us with your current attempts

Comment: Hint: lodash `groupby`, `map`

Comment: I am new to angular bro, just i had hit the api and i am getting the aboveresponse and i need to structure it to the JSON structure that i have provided. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I came up with real quick. Optimizing this code is up to you. You could probably use a `for-loop` instead of `map`. Totally up to you

```js
var data = [
   {
      "_id":{
         "year":2018
      },
      "data":[
         {
            "year":2018,
            "total":10260,
            "month":"Mar"
         }
      ],
      "overall":10260
   },
   {
      "_id":{
         "year":2019
      },
      "data":[
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14160,
            "month":"Dec"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14160,
            "month":"Nov"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14259,
            "month":"Oct"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14160,
            "month":"Sep"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14259,
            "month":"Aug"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14160,
            "month":"July"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":28518,
            "month":"Jun"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":14259,
            "month":"May"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":185185,
            "month":"Apr"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":54739,
            "month":"Mar"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":28518,
            "month":"Feb"
         },
         {
            "year":2019,
            "total":28518,
            "month":"Jan"
         }
      ],
      "overall":424895
   }
];
var res = [];
data.map((item, index) =>  {
  const overall = item.overall;
  item.data.map(i => {
   res[index] = Object.assign(res[index] || {}, {[i.month]: i.total});
  });
  res[index] = Object.assign(res[index], {
  overall, year: item._id.year
  });
  return res;
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, '  ') + '</pre>';
```

Comment: Side-note: DON'T copy the code directly. Understand it and then write it yourself.

Comment: Suree bro, will do that hereafter.